# stringbuilder and query to post data

Tags: jsp

I've the below jsp.

```
 <%@page import="java.util.Locale"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        String a = request.getParameter("comments");
        String b = request.getParameter("updatedl");
        String c = request.getParameter("sid");
        String d = request.getParameter("desc");
        String e = request.getParameter("pubcode");
        String f = request.getParameter("Type");
        String g = request.getParameter("status");


        String h = null;
        if (null != request.getParameter("DateRec")) {
            h = request.getParameter("DateRec");
        }
        String i = null;
        if (null != request.getParameter("startD")) {
            i = request.getParameter("startD");
        }
        String j = null;
        if (null != request.getParameter("AssignedD")) {
            j = request.getParameter("AssignedD");
        }
        String k = null;
        if (null != request.getParameter("sentToAE")) {
            k = request.getParameter("sentToAE");
        }
        String l = null;
        if (null != request.getParameter("RespFrmAE")) {
            l = request.getParameter("RespFrmAE");
        }
        String m = null;
        if (null != request.getParameter("VWRCmp")) {
            l = request.getParameter("VWRCmp");
        }
        String n = request.getParameter("PS");
        String o = request.getParameter("TEst");
        String p = request.getParameter("Units");
        String q = null;
        if (null != request.getParameter("VWR")) {
            l = request.getParameter("VWR");
        }
        String r = request.getParameter("IE");
        String s = null;
        if (null != request.getParameter("RevDate")) {
            s = request.getParameter("RevDate");
        }
        String t = request.getParameter("ReviewS");

        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=C:/jus/Excel1.xls; ReadOnly=true;");

        StringBuilder sc=new StringBuilder();


        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String query = "insert into [Feb$] ([comments],[No of lines updated in PSIS],[Shipment ID],"
                + "[SAP TXT Description],[Phoenix Pub Code], [Product Type], [Status of the job],[Date Request received],"
                + "[Start Date], [Date assigned],[Date file sent to AE],[Date response from AE],"
                + "[Date completed --VWR], [Assigned to PS], [Time Estimate],[Units], [Date file needs to be sent to Vendor (VWR)],"
                + "[Internal Errors],[Review Date],[Review Sent (Yes/No)]) values ('" + a + "','" + b + "','" + c + "','" + d + "','" + e + "','" + f + "','" + g + "','" + h + "','" + i + "','" + j + "','" + k + "','" + l + "','" + m + "','" + n + "','" + o + "','" + p + "','" + q + "','" + r + "','" + s + "','" + t + "')";

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        int new1 = ps.executeUpdate();

        String UR = "success.jsp";
        response.sendRedirect(UR);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

%>
```

here i want to post data to an excel sheet and i want to make the query using stringbuilder, so that the null values(as initialized in my program above), are null, these should be skipped in the query, and if they have values, then they should be considered. please let me know how i can do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use String builder as below:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

String query = "insert into [Feb$] ([comments],[No of lines updated in PSIS],[Shipment ID],"
                + "[SAP TXT Description],[Phoenix Pub Code], [Product Type], [Status of the job],[Date Request received],"
                + "[Start Date], [Date assigned],[Date file sent to AE],[Date response from AE],"
                + "[Date completed --VWR], [Assigned to PS], [Time Estimate],[Units], [Date file needs to be sent to Vendor (VWR)],"
                + "[Internal Errors],[Review Date],[Review Sent (Yes/No)]) values ('" + a + "','" + b + "','" + c + "','" + d + "','" + e + "','" + f + "','" + g;

sb.append(query);
if(h==null && i==null &&b j==null && k==null)
sb.append(+ "')");
if(h!=null)
sb.append("','" + h);
if(i!=null)
sb.append("','" + i);
if(j!=null)
sb.append("','" + j);
if(k!=null)
sb.append("','" + k);
.
.
.
```

finally convert your sb to String as:

```
String dynamicQuery = sb.toString();
```